# MySQL Order By with Limit to MS SQL Order By

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently rewriting a MySQL stored procedure to a MS SQL stored procedure and I've encountered an issue.

In the MySQL Stored Procedure there is a cursor that selects a value based off its most recent date (effdate) and places it into a variable (thesttax).

```
SELECT stax FR transfers where masterkey = skey and effdate <= CURRENT_DATE() 
order by effdate desc limit 1 into thesttax;
```

After doing some research I found that when using MS SQL you must utilize TOP, since there is no use of LIMIT in MSSQL Sql Server.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to rewrite this MySQL Statement into a MS SQL statement. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost like the other answer but using TOP you get something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @thesttax = stax
FROM transfers 
WHERE masterkey = @skey and effdate <= CURRENT_DATE() 
ORDER BY effdate DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT @thesttax = stax
FROM transfers 
WHERE masterkey = @skey and effdate <= CURRENT_DATE() 
ORDER BY effdate DESC;
```